# miss symfony / http-foundation during themosis Installation

Tags: php, symfony

I'm just want to install themosis to start new project and i have some problem during installation.

```
composer create-project themosis/themosis myProject
```

and the installation fails because obviously missing a package symfony.

```
Installing themosis/themosis (1.2.3)
  - Installing themosis/themosis (1.2.3)
    Loading from cache

Created project in myProject
Loading composer repositories with package information
Warning: Accessing wpackagist.org over http which is an insecure protocol.
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - themosis/framework 1.2.3 requires symfony/http-foundation 2.4.2 -> no matching package found.
    - themosis/framework 1.2.2 requires symfony/http-foundation 2.4.2 -> no matching package found.
    - themosis/framework 1.2.1 requires symfony/http-foundation 2.4.2 -> no matching package found.
    - themosis/framework 1.2.0 requires symfony/http-foundation 2.4.2 -> no matching package found.
    - Installation request for themosis/framework 1.2.* -> satisfiable by themosis/framework[1.2.0, 1.2.1, 1.2.2, 1.2.3].

Potential causes:
 - A typo in the package name
 - The package is not available in a stable-enough version according to your minimum-stability setting
   see  for more details.

Read  for further common problems.
```

I 'm new to this framework and have already done tests and everything worked on my local machine .
Would you have a solution to continue the install of themosis

Thanks for your help.

Comment: There is a fresh bug of missing stable tags on symfony/http-foundation. You can report that at symfony/symfony repository.

Comment: thanks tomas,
I back report this info immediately

Answer (score 0):

I was bug on packagist. Now it's fixed. Go try it!