# Creating a Laravel project. Error '..requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages'

Tags: php, git, laravel, composer-php, laravel-5

I am trying to create a laravel project. I am refering the documentation provided on its website. After i provide this command

```
composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel blog
```

I get these errors when trying to do so. I am new to Laravel. I have followed all steps closely to setup a laravel project, but now i am stuck at this problem. I couldn't find a solution after googling the error.

```
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
- laravel/framework v5.2.9 requires symfony/http-foundation 2.8.*|3.0.* -> satisfiable by symfony/http-foundation[2.8.x-dev, 3.0.x-dev] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
- laravel/framework v5.2.8 requires symfony/http-foundation 2.8.*|3.0.* -> satisfiable by symfony/http-foundation[2.8.x-dev, 3.0.x-dev] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
- laravel/framework v5.2.7 requires symfony/http-foundation 2.8.*|3.0.* -> satisfiable by symfony/http-foundation[2.8.x-dev, 3.0.x-dev] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
- laravel/framework v5.2.6 requires symfony/http-foundation 2.8.*|3.0.* -> satisfiable by symfony/http-foundation[2.8.x-dev, 3.0.x-dev] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
- laravel/framework v5.2.5 requires symfony/http-foundation 2.8.*|3.0.* -> satisfiable by symfony/http-foundation[2.8.x-dev, 3.0.x-dev] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
- laravel/framework v5.2.4 requires symfony/http-foundation 2.8.*|3.0.* -> satisfiable by symfony/http-foundation[2.8.x-dev, 3.0.x-dev] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
- laravel/framework v5.2.39 requires symfony/http-foundation 2.8.*|3.0.* -> satisfiable by symfony/http-foundation[2.8.x-dev, 3.0.x-dev] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
- laravel/framework v5.2.38 requires symfony/http-foundation 2.8.*|3.0.* -> satisfiable by symfony/http-foundation[2.8.x-dev, 3.0.x-dev] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
- laravel/framework v5.2.37 requires symfony/http-foundation 2.8.*|3.0.* -> satisfiable by symfony/http-foundation[2.8.x-dev, 3.0.x-dev] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
- laravel/framework v5.2.36 requires symfony/http-foundation 2.8.*|3.0.* -> satisfiable by symfony/http-foundation[2.8.x-dev, 3.0.x-dev] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
- laravel/framework v5.2.35 requires symfony/http-foundation 2.8.*|3.0.* -> satisfiable by symfony/http-foundation[2.8.x-dev, 3.0.x-dev] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
- laravel/framework v5.2.34 requires symfony/http-foundation 2.8.*|3.0.* -> satisfiable by symfony/http-foundation[2.8.x-dev, 3.0.x-dev] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
- laravel/framework v5.2.33 requires symfony/http-foundation 2.8.*|3.0.* -> satisfiable by symfony/http-foundation[2.8.x-dev, 3.0.x-dev] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
- laravel/framework v5.2.32 requires symfony/http-foundation 2.8.*|3.0.* -> satisfiable by symfony/http-foundation[2.8.x-dev, 3.0.x-dev] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
- laravel/framework v5.2.31 requires symfony/http-foundation 2.8.*|3.0.* -> satisfiable by symfony/http-foundation[2.8.x-dev, 3.0.x-dev] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
- laravel/framework v5.2.30 requires symfony/http-foundation 2.8.*|3.0.* -> satisfiable by symfony/http-foundation[2.8.x-dev, 3.0.x-dev] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
- laravel/framework v5.2.3 requires symfony/http-foundation 2.8.*|3.0.* -> satisfiable by symfony/http-foundation[2.8.x-dev, 3.0.x-dev] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
- laravel/framework v5.2.29 requires symfony/http-foundation 2.8.*|3.0.* -> satisfiable by symfony/http-foundation[2.8.x-dev, 3.0.x-dev] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
- laravel/framework v5.2.28 requires symfony/http-foundation 2.8.*|3.0.* -> satisfiable by symfony/http-foundation[2.8.x-dev, 3.0.x-dev] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
- laravel/framework v5.2.27 requires symfony/http-foundation 2.8.*|3.0.* -> satisfiable by symfony/http-foundation[2.8.x-dev, 3.0.x-dev] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
- laravel/framework v5.2.26 requires symfony/http-foundation 2.8.*|3.0.* -> satisfiable by symfony/http-foundation[2.8.x-dev, 3.0.x-dev] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
- laravel/framework v5.2.25 requires symfony/http-foundation 2.8.*|3.0.* -> satisfiable by symfony/http-foundation[2.8.x-dev, 3.0.x-dev] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
- laravel/framework v5.2.24 requires symfony/http-foundation 2.8.*|3.0.* -> satisfiable by symfony/http-foundation[2.8.x-dev, 3.0.x-dev] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
- laravel/framework v5.2.23 requires symfony/http-foundation 2.8.*|3.0.* -> satisfiable by symfony/http-foundation[2.8.x-dev, 3.0.x-dev] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
- laravel/framework v5.2.22 requires symfony/http-foundation 2.8.*|3.0.* -> satisfiable by symfony/http-foundation[2.8.x-dev, 3.0.x-dev] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
- laravel/framework v5.2.21 requires symfony/http-foundation 2.8.*|3.0.* -> satisfiable by symfony/http-foundation[2.8.x-dev, 3.0.x-dev] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
- laravel/framework v5.2.20 requires symfony/http-foundation 2.8.*|3.0.* -> satisfiable by symfony/http-foundation[2.8.x-dev, 3.0.x-dev] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
- laravel/framework v5.2.2 requires symfony/http-foundation 2.8.*|3.0.* -> satisfiable by symfony/http-foundation[2.8.x-dev, 3.0.x-dev] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
- laravel/framework v5.2.19 requires symfony/http-foundation 2.8.*|3.0.* -> satisfiable by symfony/http-foundation[2.8.x-dev, 3.0.x-dev] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
- laravel/framework v5.2.18 requires symfony/http-foundation 2.8.*|3.0.* -> satisfiable by symfony/http-foundation[2.8.x-dev, 3.0.x-dev] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
- laravel/framework v5.2.17 requires symfony/http-foundation 2.8.*|3.0.* -> satisfiable by symfony/http-foundation[2.8.x-dev, 3.0.x-dev] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
- laravel/framework v5.2.16 requires symfony/http-foundation 2.8.*|3.0.* -> satisfiable by symfony/http-foundation[2.8.x-dev, 3.0.x-dev] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
- laravel/framework v5.2.15 requires symfony/http-foundation 2.8.*|3.0.* -> satisfiable by symfony/http-foundation[2.8.x-dev, 3.0.x-dev] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
- laravel/framework v5.2.14 requires symfony/http-foundation 2.8.*|3.0.* -> satisfiable by symfony/http-foundation[2.8.x-dev, 3.0.x-dev] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
- laravel/framework v5.2.13 requires symfony/http-foundation 2.8.*|3.0.* -> satisfiable by symfony/http-foundation[2.8.x-dev, 3.0.x-dev] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
- laravel/framework v5.2.12 requires symfony/http-foundation 2.8.*|3.0.* -> satisfiable by symfony/http-foundation[2.8.x-dev, 3.0.x-dev] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
- laravel/framework v5.2.11 requires symfony/http-foundation 2.8.*|3.0.* -> satisfiable by symfony/http-foundation[2.8.x-dev, 3.0.x-dev] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
- laravel/framework v5.2.10 requires symfony/http-foundation 2.8.*|3.0.* -> satisfiable by symfony/http-foundation[2.8.x-dev, 3.0.x-dev] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
- laravel/framework v5.2.1 requires symfony/http-foundation 2.8.*|3.0.* -> satisfiable by symfony/http-foundation[2.8.x-dev, 3.0.x-dev] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
- laravel/framework v5.2.0 requires symfony/http-foundation 2.8.*|3.0.* -> satisfiable by symfony/http-foundation[2.8.x-dev, 3.0.x-dev] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
- Installation request for laravel/framework 5.2.* -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v5.2.0, v5.2.1, v5.2.10, v5.2.11, v5.2.12, v5.2.13, v5.2.14, v5.2.15, v5.2.16, v5.2.17, v5.2.18, v5.2.19, v5.2.2, v5.2.20, v5.2.21, v5.2.22, v5.2.23, v5.2.24, v5.2.25, v5.2.26, v5.2.27, v5.2.28, v5.2.29, v5.2.3, v5.2.30, v5.2.31, v5.2.32, v5.2.33, v5.2.34, v5.2.35, v5.2.36, v5.2.37, v5.2.38, v5.2.39, v5.2.4, v5.2.5, v5.2.6, v5.2.7, v5.2.8, v5.2.9].
```

Answer (score 0):

I have post the same question for another framework [miss symfony / http-foundation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38423895/miss-symfony-http-foundation-during-themosis-installation)
and i have received this response

> There is a fresh bug of missing stable tags

I report the bug to symfony repository